# Availability by day and week

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I'm trying to come up with a database structure to account for products that are available on certain days of week and on certain weeks ( odd / even )

An example: 
- product1 is available for selling Mondays in odd weeks
- product2 is available everyday on even weeks
- product3 is available on weekends

I thought of isolating the availability in a second table with the product as fk and each condition on a separate row like so:

```
fk_prod1    weekday    1
fk_prod1    weekparity    1
fk_prod2    onweekday    1
fk_prod1    weekparity    0
```

In this form I don't know how I would get the products that are available for today, for the rest of the week and next week.

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Queries are also much appreciated!

Comment: Can a product be available on Monday of one week and Wednesday of the following week? Can a product be available on more than 1 day in the same week? Can a product be available only every 3rd week ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help out :) Might needed adjusted depending on your circumstances with the program but heres an idea:

Table 1: Products

This could hold ProductID, ProductName
So a row could look like this: `1, product1`

Table 2: ProductDayMatrix (ProductDayID,ProductDay)

- 1,Monday
- 2,Tuesday
- 3,Wednesday
- 4,Thursday
- 5,Friday
- 6,Saturday
- 7,Sunday

Table 3: ProductWeekMatrix (ProductWeekID, ProductWeek)

- 1 = odd weeks
- 2 = even weeks

or like

- 1, Week1
- 2, Week2
- 3, Week3
- 4, Week4

Finally then Table 4:
Product Matrix: (ProductID,ProductDayID,ProductWeekID)

This could hold your products and their corresponding data. So you would insert data into this table with your information and it would look like this.

(1,4,2) = Product 1, On a Thursday, on the even weeks.

**Or** if things need multiple conditions have 2 different tables that would hold the day information.

Like: ProductAvailablityMatrixDay & ProductAvailabilityMatrixWeek

Then those could hold mulitple values for each so if product 1 was on monday and thursday you could insert: (1,1) & (1,4). Then reading from that table would tell you that product 1 was on day 1 and 4. Same goes with the weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be worth considering an approach similar to the way cron jobs are structured?

Your day of the week will always be 1-7
Your week of the month will always be 1-6

So using LIKE would give 0 possible conflicts where 1 could be matched to 10 for example as you won't ever have 2 digits.

So if your product1 it could be:

`day = 1
week = 1,3,5`

For product2 it would be:

`day = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
week=2,4,6`

For product3 it would be:

`day=6,7
week=1,2,3,4,5,6` (September this year spans 6 different weeks)

The your queries would be something like:

`Today:
"SELECT * FROM availability WHERE day LIKE '%".date("N")."%' AND week LIKE %".(date("W")-date("W",strtotime("first day of the month")))."%'";
// this is using some PHP to get the week of the days of the week and week of the month.`

`Tomorrow:
"SELECT * FROM availability WHERE day LIKE '%".date("N",strtotime("tomorrow")."%' AND week LIKE %".(date("W",strtotime("tomorrow"))-date("W",strtotime("first day of the month")))."%'";
// this again is using some PHP to get the week of the days of the week and week of the month - you can achieve the same with just MYSQL but I'm more familiar with PHP to give you an idea.`

I'm not saying its perfect but unless your going to do more with these rows I don't think the use of foreign keys is going to help you? Hope that helps?